# python zipfile module on windows, too many slashes

Tags: python, windows, zip, pygame

I'm currently making a game using python 2.7 and pygame 1.9. I store my graphics in `graphics.dat`, which is just a renamed zip file. The function I use to load graphics into the game is this:

```
import pygame, zipfile, tarfile sys, os
from cStringIO import StringIO
from pygame.locals import *
def loadImage(filename, noAlpha=False):
    baseZip = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join("..", "Data", "graphics.dat"))
    imgData = baseZip.read(filename) #the "filename" argument is already os.path.join()'ed when I pass it to the function
    imgDataIO = StringIO(imgData)
    finalFileName = os.path.split(filename)
    preSurf = pygame.image.load(imgDataIO, finalFileName[1])
    if noAlpha:
        resultSurf = preSurf.convert()
    else:
        resultSurf = preSurf.convert_alpha()
    baseZip.close()
    return resultSurf
```

On linux (Ubuntu 12.04) it works perfectly, but on windows it always raises an error

> "No item named folder\\\\\\\file.png in the archive"

(I'm not on Windows right now so I can't copy the exact error text, but it has a lot of "\"s).

Is there a solution?

Comment: if your using os.path.join it should find it ... assumming you are using the right path

Comment: which line are you getting the error in? Also, print the value of finalFileName please.
For copying error text from windows, use redirection operator `>` in command line and redirect the output to a file

Comment: the finalFileName var is just an optional hint to tell pygame the image is a png type, no real use on the importing

Comment: which line are you getting the error in?

Comment: Line 7. I put a "print filename" before trying to load the image and it prints right, "folder\image.png", but when I use the read() function it returns "KeyError: There is no item named 'folder\\\\image.png' in the archive

Comment: I think you need to split `filename` with `'\'` and use only `image.png` from it, rather than `folder\image.png`. Just try and let us know if it worked. I am guessing this because I do not know the contents of the zip file as well as your current working directory.

Comment: it worked! moving the files to the root folder of the zip file "solved" the problem. Now I'll have to create multiple zip files to organize different types of graphics, but at least it's working. Thank you GodMan

Comment: Ok. great. moving my comment to an asnwer so that you can accpet and close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to split filename with '\' and use only image.png from it, rather than folder\image.png. Just try and let us know if it worked. I am guessing this because I do not know the contents of the zip file as well as your current working directory

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that filenames in zip files are always stored with forward slashes, never backslashes.

Thus, when loading your image, you'll have to use a path with forward slashes as path separators, e.g. 'folder/image.png'.